Windows update history in .Net 6
I am converting my Net framework application to .Net 6 where we have code to get all windows update history using  CreateUpdateSearcher (Interop.WUApiLib;)
There is no alternate of Interop.WUApiLibin .net 6
In .net 6 is there any issue to use Interop.WUApiLib using com reffrence in .net 6
Will be used for windows only

Use Win32_QuickFixEngineering. See About Configuration Manager WMI programming.

Thanks @Richard but values and count are different I have tried the same
